# Are there any multiline comments in fish?

Tags: shell, fish

I am learning Fish and I want to know how to make multiline comments but the docs are hard to understand.

Any Help Apprecited.

Comment: No, though the documentation could be clearer. (I can't even find an explicit reference that `#` introduces a rest-of-line comment.)

Comment: oh ok, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a quoted string that spans multiple lines to a no-op command. This also works in other shells.

```
: '
This is a multi-line
comment.
'
```

The `:` command is an alias to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation doesn't seem to include an explicit references for how to add a comment to a `fish` script. The implication via examples is that the only comment available is the POSIX-shell style rest-of-line comment that starts with an unquoted `#`.